# How to add items to a list? Flutter

Tags: list, flutter

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
Here is my ListItems class:

  

      class ListItems {
      String? title;
      String? text;
      DateTime? selectedDayTime;
    
      ListItems(
          {required this.title, required this.text, required this.selectedDayTime});
    }
```

In my AddTask class, I'm trying to add some items to my list. Here is my code:

```
    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          itemList.add(
                            ListItems(
                              title: _titleController.text,
                              text: _textController.text,
                              selectedDayTime: _selectedDay,
                            ),
                          );
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        });
                        print(itemList.length);
                      },
                      child: Text("Add Task"),
                    ),
```

itemList is a List list. However, everytime I try to add new item to my itemList, itemList.length never changes. I dont know why this happening so I need help.

Comment: Swap Navigator with print line and make list as List<List items>

Comment: @JahidulIslam it worked. Length changes now. However, can't I use Navigator.pop now? Cuz I have to pop the page back to see the list items on my other screen.

Comment: Can i make it as answer?

Comment: Yes,please. @JahidulIslam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap Navigator with print line.

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          itemList.add(
                            ListItems(
                              title: _titleController.text,
                              text: _textController.text,
                              selectedDayTime: _selectedDay,
                            ),
                          );
                          print(itemList.length);
                          //Navigator.pop(context); keep it here also
                        });
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text("Add Task"),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you include your print statement inside the `setState`? I don't see any reason for your code not to work.

You could also try to type your `itemList` to be of type `List<ListItems>`, if you haven't already. I don't think it's causing any issues, but it can't hurt to be thorough.

Comment: My itemList implementation exactly like you said. The problem is when I try to add new ListItems objects to itemList, length never changes so I cant understand if I already added the object or not.